# Byref vs Byval vba clarification

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was writing some VBA to futher my understanding of Byref and Byval. This is what I am using:

```
Private Function Checkcase()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Debug.Print i
    num(i)
    Debug.Print i
    End Function


Public Function num(ByRef i As Integer)
    i = 5
End Function
```

**Output**
**1

1**

However, when I use the `call` keyword in front of `num(i)` like:

```
call num(i)
```

The output changes to
**1

5**

I was expecting the output to be 1 and 5 in both cases as I am changing the reference of the variable i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num(i)` is the error here. When you call a sub or a function without getting the return value, you must not put parentheses around the arguments.

When you pass arguments with parentheses to a function expecting `ByRef` arguments, those are automatically cast to `ByVal`.

Either use `Call num(i)` or remove the parentheses `num i`

References: [Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement) :

> If you omit the Call keyword, you also must omit the parentheses around argumentlist.

As always, [Cpearson site is a must read](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx)

Comment: If you put parentheses around arguments when they are more than one, the compiler will bug you with a "syntax error", but when there is only one argument it will think that you want an explicit `ByVal`.